# JavaScript new Function confusion

Tags: javascript, function, object

While reading Learning JavaScript 2nd edition, I see a block of code in Chapter 13: Creating Custom JavaScript Objects.

```
var oneOff = new Function () {
    this.variablea = "variablea";
    this.method = function () {
        return xxx;
    }
}
```

It is said that it is the same as:

```
var oneOff = new Object();
oneOff.variablea = "variablea";
oneOff.method = function () {...};
```

But I don't know what new Function () {..} is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The look it up on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) ?

Comment: this usage is not the same as "new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)" mentioned on MDN

Comment: I think you misread the example, because what your question states is simply wrong. That first piece of code is a syntax error, as you could verify by typing it into a browser console.

Comment: Ya, that's a syntax error if using capital letter 'F' and it seems to a typo in the book (I've it on hand and reading page 312, so I'm sure the author is using 'Function'). But since the book was published several years ago, I am not sure if this was once a legal syntax in the past.

Comment: @adeneo The MDN documentation keeps referring to a `function object` is that the same as an object in javscript?  The terminology is throwing me off.  Althought I usually prefer MDN documentation I think the W3Schools documentation is slightly clearer on this one: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: The book really says `new Function()` [Learning JavaScript: Add Sparkle and Life to Your Web Pages - P312](http://books.google.de/books?id=3On-moJDuO0C&pg=PA312)

Comment: @WaiKitKung Recommended reading: http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/

Answer (score 2):

When using new function() { /*  */ }, you are not creating a new function, but rather an object.
It is just a standard use of new with a constructor function, like in :

```
var oneInstance = new ConstructorFunction();

function ConstructorFunction() {
         this.var1 = 'val1';
         this.method1 = function() { } ;
}
```

The difference is that the constructor is defined right at the time of instantiation, and we omit to call the function, which is legal (although confusing i think).

I find it somehow clearer with some brackets, and making explicit the call to the constructor :

```
var oneOff = new  ( function () {
  this.variablea = "variablea";
  this.method = function () {
    return xxx;
  };
} ) () ;
```

but for creating just one single object, one would rather use the simple object notation :

```
var oneOff = {
  variablea : 'valuea',
  method    : function () { return xxx; }
}
```

How do they compare in performances  ?

For the new function() {} method, creating the object will require to first create a function, then execute that function within a 'new' context. 
On the other hand, object litteral just create ...one object, so it's less time and less garbage created.

On use performances of the two types of objects (time to read/write a property /use a method) it's very hard to say since all javascript interpreters are very complex and very different. When and how do they decide to optimize a part of the code is something you can't really know before benchmarking. - And benchmarking is not an easy task also because of those 'random' optimisations. My bet is that they should be very close in use performance, let us know if you take the time to do some measures.

Comment: The parenthesis added makes it clear to me. The last () is optional as I know. Is that identical to the object literal in terms of performance and the compiler interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

`new function` (notice `F` is lowercase) is one of the many ways of creating an object in Javascript.  After the code is interpreted an object will be assigned to `oneOff` with `variablea` and `method` properties.

Another way to achieve this is to use the object literal notation:

```
var oneOff = {
    variablea:"variablea",
    method:function () {
        return xxx; //this will be undefined
    }
}
```

This works fine if you only need one instance of `oneOff` however if you need multiple instances of `oneOff` you can use the function constructor as follows:

```
function OneOff(){
    this.variablea = "variablea";
}

OneOff.prototype.method = function(){
   return xxx; //one again undefined
}

var firstOneOff = new OneOff();
var secondOneOff = new OneOff();
```

Comment: Anyone want to explain the downvotes?  Would be interested in learning where I'm off on this one.

Comment: I gave a upvote. The method you present is really the typical usage. I always attach to the function statements and function literals because they are clear to people what I am doing.

Comment: @WaiKitKung thanks for the upvote, hope this was helpful.  I'm always interested in hearing the opinions of those who downvote. If it is a legitimate downvote and they explain their reasoning you get the most value from SO.