# What's the difference between these two function expressions?

Tags: javascript

Please correct me if I am wrong. The snippet below is a function statement:

```
function foo() {}
```

where as the ones below are all function expressions.

```
var foo = function() { } // or
var foo = function foo() { } // or 
var foo = new function() { }
```

My question is, what is the difference between these two forms of a function expression?

```
var foo = function() { } // and
var foo = new function() { }
```

Is the second one also a constructor expression? And if it is, of which class (I am at a loss of words here, I know JavaScript does not have classes, but by class, here, I mean template or function or prototype)

**Update**

Those who have provided links to related questions, thank you very much. I really appreciate it. I am trying to learn this language and at this point, honestly, I am so nascent in my judgement that I cannot tell if they're all the same question. I do know that the more I read, although I find it all very fascinating, the more it confuses me at this stage. I will probably take time to fully understand the beauty of this wonderful language. Meanwhile, please do keep mentioning other related threads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript new Function confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585123/javascript-new-function-confusion)

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of that question. That one is about using the Function constructor to instantiate functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
var foo = function() { }
```

instantiates a function and assigns to `foo` a reference to that function.

This

```
var foo = new function() { }
```

instantiates a function, *calls it* with a new object as its context, and assigns the newly-created object (or the object return value from the function) as the value of `foo`. The function itself is discarded unless it by some means manages to return itself.

The second piece of code is, or should be, fairly rare in code not written by a confused person.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very nicely explained. I am a little confused, though. So, if the statement was: 

`var foo = new function { return new Integer(2); }`, then would foo be equal to an Integer object?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 yes, that's right - it's sort-of a strange practice to do that, but it makes sense sometimes. Personally I don't think I've ever written such code. That's only true when the constructor function returns an object of some type, too - if it returns something like a number or string, then the value of the `new` expression is the newly-allocated object and the return value is ignored.

Comment: Thank you once more. I have to read that many times, honestly. The more I see other threads and read other code, I am confused. But thank you so much. You've been extremely helpful. It's me. Or I guess it's JavaScript. It probably takes time to *click*. Do you recommend a good source that I should pursue consistently to *get it*?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 well this sort of arcana is something that might be best understood from the spec itself (which is dense, but at least it's thorough). However it's really not terribly *practical* knowledge, as it's usually easier to just avoid doing weird stuff :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I love languages and usually like to read specs. I had it on my todo list to read ECMA 6. I guess it'll be some time before I get to that, though. Meanwhile, I think I'll just read from the MDN, right?

Comment: Just one more quesiton, though. So, from reading what you said again and again, I am wondering if `var foo = new function() { }` is the same as `var foo = Object.create(Object.prototype);`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 it's *almost* the same - the anonymous function in the first one (the `new` expression) will have an empty prototype object by default. Therefore, it'll have the same net effect, but there'll be an extra (empty) object in the new object's prototype chain. (It's empty, so it won't do anything really.)

Answer (score 1):

A Function Expression defines a function as a part of a larger expression syntax (typically a variable assignment ). Functions defined via Functions Expressions can be named or anonymous.

The following are examples of function expression that create a function and assign to the variable `foo`:

```
var foo = function() { }

var foo = function foo() { }
```

When you use the `new` keyword it does not create a function, it just creates an object and assigns it to the variable `foo`, the instantiated function gets called as well.

```
var foo = new function() { }
```

Comment: The `new` expression does cause an object to be created, but the instantiated function is definitely called.

Comment: Correct, the function is called.

Comment: @Pointy - Just saw your answer :) It's more clearly explained. +1 for that.